# How to dim part of the syntax-highlighted source?

Tags: minted, emphasis

I'd like to typeset a (LaTeX) source code with syntax highlighting (I guess I'm going to use `minted`, but I haven't decided that for sure yet).  I'd like to have *complete* examples (with `\documentclass` etc.), and so I would like to have the "important" parts somehow emphasized.  I thought about dimming the "unimportant" stuff (e.g., the preamble when I'm talking about e.g. lists, and the contents of the file when I'm talking about the preamble, etc.).

How to achieve that?

Comment: `minted` hands the task to `pygmentize` that creates a file understandable to `Verbatim` of `fancyvrb`. It doesn't interpret the listing in any way.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple possibilities for working with `minted`. Both would need a little additional refinement to get the spacing correct.

First, you could redefine `fancyvrb`'s `\FancyVerbFormatLine` to do something special for the lines you want highlighted (or something to "dim" the other lines).  Here's code that creates a new `fancyvrb` option `highlight` that puts all lines in a specified range in a colorbox.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\FV@parsehighlight[#1-#2]{%
  \edef\FV@starthighlight{#1}%
  \edef\FV@endhighlight{#2}}
\define@key{FV}{highlight}{%
  \FV@parsehighlight[#1]%
  \renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
    \ifnum\numexpr\FV@starthighlight\relax>\FV@CodeLineNo
      ##1
    \else
      \ifnum\numexpr\FV@endhighlight\relax<\FV@CodeLineNo
        ##1
      \else
        \colorbox{yellow}{\hbox to\linewidth{##1\vphantom{fg}}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\minted@define@extra{highlight}
\makeatother
```

Example usage:  `\inputminted[highlight=6-25]{latex}{x.tex}`.

A second approach is to use `\inputminted` multiple times on the same file, each time bringing in only part of the document, and putting a frame around the part that is important.  For example, using `tcolorbox`,

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inputmintedhighlightrange}[5][]{%
  \edef\arg{#1,firstline=1,lastline=\number\numexpr#4-1\relax}%
  \expandafter\inputminted\expandafter[\arg]{#2}{#3}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter]
  \inputminted[#1,firstline=#4,lastline=#5]{#2}{#3}%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \edef\arg{#1,firstline=\number\numexpr#5+1\relax}%
  \expandafter\inputminted\expandafter[\arg]{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
```

Example usage:  `\inputmintedhighlightrange{latex}{x.tex}{6}{25}`.